# Sending multiple commands to USB/Ethernet connected device

Tags: c#, vb.net, usb, communication, ethernet

I have a device (a cash register) which I can communicate with through **USB** or **Ethernet** commands, using either **VB.NET** or **C#** (I have 2 versions of the app and I can translate from one to another). When I send one payment command at a time, it works just fine. But if I send 2 payment commands at the same time (either from 2 Ethernet-connected computers or one Ethernet-connected and one USB-connected), it mixes the commands and all the products I sell (as a test) are put on the same receipt, when it should make 2 different receipts.

What could I do in order to make it work? (I'd prefer it to print the first receipt then the 2nd one, and if not possible at least to warn one of the users that the cash register is already in use). I asked the manufacturer about this and he said that he had not taken into consideration this action (of sending multiple commands in the same time). Is there any way I could test if the device is already in use? (perhaps using a library or a function)

If it helps, the payment command I send is built like this: using a for loop, I take the name, quantity, price and barcode from each row of a DataTable with the sold products, I build a string which is later sent to the cash receiver. After the loop reached the end of the table, I build another string that represents the payment command, which calculates the amount of money the buyer has to pay. I could also post code if this is necessary.

If you have any idea or a way to solve this, I would be more than grateful. Thank you very much for your attention, have a nice day! (:

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you create a single process that is responsible for talking to the hardware and then have the rest of your software send commands via that gatekeeper.  That way, that single process could queue all incoming requests and then send them to the hardware in the correct order.

Comment: Will try tomorrow since I left the office and I am not able to test it anymore until tomorrow. Thank you for your advice!